# setting YTickLabel matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, axis-labels

what is wrong that i can not figure out in my `YTickLabel`:

```
h2=bar(myData);
ylabels=['1';'1.5';'2';'2.5';'3'];
set(gca,'XTickLabel',applicationNames),'XTick',applicationNames),'YTickLabel',ylabel));
```

p.s: I have tried this as well with no success:

```
ax=gca
ax.YTickLabel=['1';'1.5';'2';'2.5';'3'];
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create a character array.  In this case, you are trying to create a 2D matrix where the number of columns should have the same number of characters and the number of rows denotes how many labels you have.  For your strings, the maximum number of characters per column is three (number / dot / number).  Because you have characters that are only of length 1 (i.e. just a number), you are getting an inconsistent concatenation error because it's expecting all characters to be of length 3 in the array.

What you actually need to use is a **cell** array to accommodate for the inconstant size of each `y` tick label.  Therefore:

```
ax.YTickLabel={'1';'1.5';'2';'2.5';'3'};
```

---

Alternatively, because your labels are numbers, you can simply use a numeric array instead:

```
ax.YTickLabel = [1;1.5;2;2.5;3];
```

A cell array of characters is used if you want to label the `x` and/or `y` axis to be something other than just numbers.  It's possible to label the `y` axis using text, such as:

```
ax.YTickLabel = {'John'; 'Paul'; 'George'; 'Ringo'; 'The Beatles'};
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @rayryeng, I did try that as well. in this case I am not receiving any error, (seeing this): `ax = 

    YTickLabel: [1 1.5000 2 20.5000]` but on the actual plot i don't see the changes

Comment: @Amir - Do `axis tight` and see what happens.  Also, sharing your data so we can reproduce your plot would help so that we don't suggest stuff you have already tried

Comment: actually the reason i am doing this is kinda `adjustbarbase`, i tried a plugin `.m` file but didn't work. The whole point is I would like to rename my `YTickLabel` all `+1`. By the way, `axis tight`, tighten the YTick fairly as I am observing it now

Comment: my data is just a 24*1 string.

Comment: @Amir - You also will need to set your `YTick` values in conjunction to your `YTickLabels` as well.  If you don't do this, then it just assigns the first 5 values of `y` to be what you put in `YTickLabel`... unless this is what your intention is.  You should also update your question to show us what the actual problem is.  It's not so much creating the `YTickLabel`s - it's that you are not getting what you **expect**.

Comment: Ok man thanks. Maybe that was the case. I will check on that and report here